# Get object with max frequency from Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an object with `city` and `zip` fields, let's call it `Record`.

```
public class Record() {
    private String zip;
    private String city;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Now, I have a collection of these objects, and I group them by `zip` using the following code:

```
final Collection<Record> records; //populated collection of records
final Map<String, List<Record>> recordsByZip = records.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getZip));
```

So, now I have a map where the key is the `zip` and the value is a list of `Record` objects with that `zip`.

What I want to get now is the most common `city` for each `zip`.

```
recordsByZip.forEach((zip, records) -> {
    final String mostCommonCity = //get most common city for these records
});
```

I would like to do this with all stream operations. For example, I am able to get a map of the frequency for each `city` by doing this:

```
recordsByZip.forEach((zip, entries) -> {
    final Map<String, Long> frequencyMap = entries.stream()
        .map(GisSectorFileRecord::getCity)
        .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
});
```

But I would like to be able to do a single-line stream operation that will just return the most frequent `city`.

Are there any Java 8 stream gurus out there that can work some magic on this?

Here is an [ideone sandbox](https://ideone.com/IhL5te) if you'd like to play around with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could have the following:

```
final Map<String, String> mostFrequentCities =
  records.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Record::getZip,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
              Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getCity, Collectors.counting()),
              map -> map.entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get().getKey()
            )
         ));
```

This groups each records by their zip, and by their cities, counting the number of cities for each zip. Then, the map of the number of cities by zip is post-processed to keep only the city having the maximum count.

Comment: `collectingAndThen` I knew I was missing something, but I always think about `mapping` instead. +1

Comment: Is there a way to check if the `Optional` returned by `.max()` is present in the stream operation before calling `.get()` on it?

Comment: @AndrewMairose Yes, but `.get()` is safe to call here, the map can never be empty, it will necessarily contain at least the city with the grouped by zip.

Comment: How could you call is present first? In my actual application, the map could be empty because `city` is nullable, and I call `filter` first to filter out records where `city` is `null`. So in the case that there is only one record for a `zip`, and that record has a `null` `city`, then the optional would not be present.

Comment: @AndrewMairose I see, well instead of `.get().getKey()`, you can call `.map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(null)`, which would return `null` for the most frequent city if the map is empty.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @Andrew Mairose: I don’t see, how the nullability of `getCity` should change the fact that `groupingBy` never produces empty groups, hence, `max` on a group will never produce an empty `Optional`. If you filter before collecting, a group might cease to exist, still, there won’t be empty groups.

Answer (score 1):

I think Multiset is a good choice for this kind of question. Here is code by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
Stream.of(records).map(e -> e.getCity()).filter(N::notNullOrEmpty)
      .toMultiset().maxOccurrences().get().getKey();
```

Disclosure： I'm the developer of abacus-common.

Comment: Please add code snippet (preferably) or link to code snippet (at least)